# BUF_ERROR -5 return from uncompress ZLIB

Tags: c, zlib

I am trying to unzip data in ZLIB using the uncompress function. the data to be decompressed is in a Char vector. the library was downloaded from github for C language. code below:

```
 //C
 unsigned char out[20000], u_out[20000];
 size_t size_out;
 unsigned char* in = ""; //non inserisco i dati di partenza per privacy
 int err, i;
 long int ucompSize_out; 
 long int compSize_out; 
 size_out=sizeof(out);

 //codifica in base45
 err=base45_decode(out,&size_out,in,strlen(in));
 printf("\nbase45(%s) ", (char*)out);
 printf("\n%d",err);
    
//decompressione zlib
ucompSize_out= strlen(out)+1; 
compSize_out= compressBound(ucompSize_out);
err=uncompress ((Byte *)u_out, &ucompSize_out, (const Byte *) out, compSize_out );
printf("\nzlib(\"%s\") ", (char*)u_out);
printf("\n%d",err);
```

when I run this code it returns me BUF_ERROR (-5). I read on the Zlib guide that it is a problem of space for output or input but I can not figure out how to fix it
for completeness load also the functions recalled

```
int ZEXPORT uncompress2 (dest, destLen, source, sourceLen)
Bytef *dest;
uLongf *destLen;
const Bytef *source;
uLong *sourceLen;
{
 z_stream stream;
int ZEXPORT inflateInit2_(strm, windowBits, version, stream_size)
z_streamp strm;
int windowBits;
const char *version;
int stream_size;
{
int ret;
struct inflate_state FAR *state;

if (version == Z_NULL || version[0] != ZLIB_VERSION[0] ||
    stream_size != (int)(sizeof(z_stream)))
    return Z_VERSION_ERROR;
if (strm == Z_NULL) return Z_STREAM_ERROR;
strm->msg = Z_NULL;                 /* in case we return an error */
if (strm->zalloc == (alloc_func)0) {
}
if (strm->zfree == (free_func)0)

state = (struct inflate_state FAR *)
        ZALLOC(strm, 1, sizeof(struct inflate_state));
if (state == Z_NULL) return Z_MEM_ERROR;
Tracev((stderr, "inflate: allocated\n"));
strm->state = (struct internal_state FAR *)state;
state->strm = strm;
state->window = Z_NULL;
state->mode = HEAD;     /* to pass state test in inflateReset2() */
ret = inflateReset2(strm, windowBits);
if (ret != Z_OK) {
    ZFREE(strm, state);
    strm->state = Z_NULL;
}
 return ret;
}

int ZEXPORT inflateInit_(strm, version, stream_size)
z_streamp strm;
const char *version;
int stream_size;
{
 return inflateInit2_(strm, DEF_WBITS, version, stream_size);
}
 int err;
 const uInt max = (uInt)-1;
 uLong len, left;
 Byte buf[1];    /* for detection of incomplete stream when *destLen == 0 */

 len = *sourceLen;
 if (*destLen) {
    left = *destLen;
    *destLen = 0;
}
else {
    left = 1;
    dest = buf;
}

stream.next_in = (z_const Bytef *)source;
stream.avail_in = 0;
stream.zalloc = (alloc_func)0;
stream.zfree = (free_func)0;
stream.opaque = (voidpf)0;

err = inflateInit2(&stream);
if (err != Z_OK) return err;

stream.next_out = dest;
stream.avail_out = 0;

do {
    if (stream.avail_out == 0) {
        stream.avail_out = left > (uLong)max ? max : (uInt)left;
        left -= stream.avail_out;
    }
    if (stream.avail_in == 0) {
        stream.avail_in = len > (uLong)max ? max : (uInt)len;
        len -= stream.avail_in;
    }
    err = inflate(&stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
} while (err == Z_OK);

*sourceLen -= len + stream.avail_in;
if (dest != buf)
    *destLen = stream.total_out;
else if (stream.total_out && err == Z_BUF_ERROR)
    left = 1;

inflateEnd(&stream);
return err == Z_STREAM_END ? Z_OK :
       err == Z_NEED_DICT ? Z_DATA_ERROR  :
       err == Z_BUF_ERROR && left + stream.avail_out ? Z_DATA_ERROR :
       err;
}

int ZEXPORT uncompress (dest, destLen, source, sourceLen)
Bytef *dest;
uLongf *destLen;
const Bytef *source;
uLong sourceLen;
{
 return uncompress2(dest, destLen, source, &sourceLen);
}
```

Comment: Since you're working with binary data chances are `strlen(out)` isn't going to work for you. It will return where it found the first 0. It looks like you have a parameter passed to `base45_decode` to capture the length. Use that instead.

Comment: If you have large (GB) size data you are working with, see [zlib compress() returns Z_BUF_ERROR despite buffer allocated to result of compressBound (file too big?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27231296/3422102)

Comment: my string is a few bytes, I control the data quantities, thanks

Comment: thanks  @Retired Ninja I solved my problem.

Comment: `Z_BUF_ERROR` isn't really an error. It's warning. If you can provide more input data and output space on the next call, then you can keep going with no issue.